# How to enable Modal Image in DWQA Plugin of WordPress?

Tags: images

I am using [DWQA Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dw-question-answer/) for Question and Answer Forum on my website. My problem is I am not able to enlarge inserted image. Visitors are not able to click and enlarge Image to see it properly.

You can check out the live example at this [link](https://loveumarketing.com/questions/change-blog-title-description-blogger/). Try to click on the Image it will not work.

So, my question how to enable the Modal Image in DWQA inserted Images? I want my user to click and enlarge images for better clarity?
Please Help...

Comment: This it will be better if asked directly to the Developers of the plugin.

Comment: Thank You. I will ask them also. I had shared it here assuming if someone know the answer then they will share it.